# Can you sync PSVita trophies from a NTSC Game with a PAL Account

Tags: achievements, psn, ps-vita

I know that a PSN Account is tied to the memory card which means if you wanted a NTSC (US) and PAL (UK, Aus) PSN Account you would need 2 memory cards.

With that said, in terms of trophies, can you sync trophies that were obtained from an NTSC game with a PAL PSN Account? Here's an example:

I have Atelier Totori Plus on my Australian PSN Account (PAL). If I were to get a NTSC copy of Ragnarok Oddysey and got its trophies, could I sync them to the same account as my PAL PSN Account or can I only sync it with the NTSC Account that I would use to get its DLC?

EDIT: I should note that in my example Ragnarok Oddysey is preferably a physical copy, not downloaded.

Comment: Have you already earned the trophies on the NTSC account or are you looking to start the game on one account or the other?

Comment: @Colin i'm looking to start a new game of Ragnarok Oddysey (NTSC) and have it's trophies synced to my PAL PSN Account to add to the rest of my games, i have to have the memory card bound to my NTSC PSN Account for the Ragnarok Oddysey DLC in when i play the game and i'm not too sure how trophies are stored on the PSVita so i can't do what i do with the PS3 and download the DLC from one user then switch back to my main user

Comment: Trophies are tied to your PSN Account. If you can play your US game while being signed into your Australian account, the trophies should go to your Australian account. This is possible on PS3 but I'm not sure about Vita. It sounds like you'd have to somehow copy the game to your Aus account memory card. Can the PC content manager software do this?

Comment: @YellowMegaMan No this will not work as digital purchase of the game is not tied to the australian account. If the DLC is not available in the region specific store of the account you want the trophies on I don't this it will be possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. I have a US copy of Mortal Kombat for the PSVita and its trophies sync with my PAL account just fine.

That said, it depends if you can play the game while signed in to your account, so with an NTSC Vita game **played off a game card** - it's possible, but since games downloaded are locked to a single account on the Vita, you won't be able to download an NTSC copy and play it while signed in to your PAL account.

Regarding the DLC you've mentioned - it's a different problem. You cant download DLC for NTSC games with a PAL account, nor you can play Vita DLC with an account other than the one owning it. So in your case, getting a US copy of Ragnarok Odyssey will lock you from playing and earning trophies for its DLC on your PAL account.